# Apache HttpClient - Default protocol

Tags: apache, http, https, protocols, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using **Apache HttpClient** to send a **POST** requests. How can I determine which PROTOCOL my **Apache HttpClient** instance is using for sending "https://" requests. I use following code block to send my POST requests.

```
    public void sendPostURL(String url, HashMap<String, String>params, String user, String pass) {
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    String urlContent = "";
    PostMethod method = new PostMethod("https://...");

    // Prepare connection information                                                                                                                          
    client.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent", "MyApp");


    if ( (user != null) &&(pass != null) ) {
            client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
            client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, (new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, pass)));
    }


    // Prepare parameters                                                                                                                                      
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            method.addParameter(entry.getKey(), ((entry.getValue() != null) ? entry.getValue().toString() : ""));
    }

    try{
            // HTTP execution                                                                                                                                  
        int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);



    } catch (Exception e) {
            // Exception                                                                                                                                       
            e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        method.releaseConnection();
    }

    }
```

Please guide me on how can I get the **PROTOCOL** that HttpClient is using to send the request. Also how can I override the **PROTOCOL** used. Hoping for a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol *is* HTTPS, is it not ?

Comment: I would like to know if its HTTPS with SSL or TLS. How would I be able to determine that? Also could you help me with the code snippet that i can use to fetch the PROTOCOL name with details